# Why we use ArrayList when we could have used Set for adding unique values?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, set

I found an efficient code for adding unique items using the below approach:

```
int[] values = { -5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6 };

List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int val : values)

{

   if(!list.contains(val))

   list.add(val);

}
```

I could have done the same work using  a HashSet instead of using an ArrayList. That would have helped me by not worring to check if the value already existed in the list. Why is using a Hashset not an efficient approach?

Comment: A `List` is never been intented/designed to hold unique values, so I fail to see the point of your question. If you want to hold unique values, just go ahead with a `Set`. Use the right data structure for the purpose.

Comment: An ArrayList can hold unique values just fine, it just does not ensure uniqueness. And it works better for lookup by position than for `contains` (which has to scan the list). We need more context about what he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `HashSet` does not implement the `List` interface. And the values in a `Set` are not indexed. We can't *get* value from a `Set`.

So if you just need a storage for unique values, then you can safely use a `Set` implementation. If you need to keep insertion order or if you need any other functionality of `List` implementations *and* uniqueness, then use the method from your question: decorate an existing `List` implementation and add functionality to reject duplicates.

You asked about efficiency: `ArrayList` is backed by an array and pretty fast. But the time complexity for `contains()` is O(n) - to iterate we have look at each and every element in worst case.

`HashSet` is more or less a decorator of a full blown `HashMap`, somewhat heavier compared to an `array`. But the time complexity for `contains` is O(1) - the check is done in constant time, regardless how many items are inside the map.

If you just want to iterate - a specialized `List` implementation should be slightly faster - both have a time complexity of O(n) for the iteration (no surprise) but reading from an array is easier then reading from a Map.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a lovely answer. Thanks a lot to other friend also for giving their time. I think I should read more about calculating time complexcities of loops. @ all thanks again. Regards, krishna

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `HashSet` is a *much* better approach than `ArrayList`. Your code runs in O(n) for `HashSet`, and O(n²) for `ArrayList`.

But, one thing to keep in mind: elements in `HashSet` are not kept in any particular order. If you want to keep order *and* have fast lookups, use `LinkedHashSet`. (Everything has a cost, though; in this case, `LinkedHashSet` uses more memory than `HashSet`.)

Comment: However, at least in the example `n` is very small. And the elements are distinct anyway. Why use a List when he can just use the original array? Without some more context, it is hard to give advice here.

Comment: @Thilo: That is true, re the need for more context.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wanted to count the unique values in an array. Ithought of adding uniuqe values to th elist and then getting the size of the list to get the count of the unique values. But now after reading your answer I feel i should use HashSet and then add the values to it and then getting the size. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is. The premise to your question is flawed.

Use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and it's easier:

`Set set = Sets.newTreeSet( values );` //or HashSet

Comment: If you're using Guava, I'd much rather use `ImmutableSet.of(-5, -3, -1, 0, 3, 6)` instead. Immutability FTW. :-)

Comment: Lol, fair enough. I assumed `values` isn't actually defined, or else Arrays.asList() could have built the arraylist, and there's no need to check for duplicates. ;)

Comment: Okay. How about: `ImmutableSet.copyOf(values)`. Still a set, still immutable. :-)

Comment: Whoever said the data was immutable? :P 10:1 any code following from the example source adds values, re-assigns the list reference, and has multiple return points. 

jk. Yeah, `ImmutableSet.of` is another option.